# Will my luggage go all the way through?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, luggage

I have a flight tomorrow which I'm flying out of Heathrow to Houston and then to Denver, I was a little curious if my luggage will go through all the way to my final destination which is Denver, or will I need to collect the luggage In Houston and re check it in?

Answer (score 5):

Houston will be your port of entry into the United States. As such, your bags should be tagged through to Denver, but you'll have to pick them up and take them through customs in Houston.

You will:

- Exit the plane in Houston
- Go through US Immigration
- Claim your checked luggage at the baggage carousel
- Exit through US Customs
- Follow the signs for "connecting flights" to the bag drop, where an agent will collect your checked luggage from you
- Proceed to the gate for your flight to Denver, going through TSA airport security

When you get to Denver, your checked bags will, assuming all goes well, come out at the baggage claim, where you can pick them up and go on your way.

Comment: @JoshSmith Have a good trip!